# Can a non-mount pull a cart?

Tags: dnd-5e, mount, vehicles

To illustrate the situation in a more relatable way, I have a lvl 3 halfling drakewarden ranger who wants to circumvent the whole "it only becomes a mount at lvl 7" argument by hitching it to a rickshaw, as shown:

[image: Adam Savage on his Rickshaw, pulled by a small quadrupedal robot]

I could not find anything mentioning if a wagon (or in this case, a chariot would be the closest equivalent) could be pulled by a small-sized creature, but I did find the [Lifting and Carrying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#LiftingandCarrying) section of D&DBeyond quite interesting:

> **Carrying Capacity.** Your carrying capacity is your Strength score multiplied by 15. This is the weight (in pounds) that you can carry, which is high enough that most characters don't usually have to worry about it.
>
> **Push, Drag, or Lift.** You can push, drag, or lift a weight in pounds up to twice your carrying capacity (or 30 times your Strength score). While pushing or dragging weight in excess of your carrying capacity, your speed drops to 5 feet.
>
> **Size and Strength.** Larger creatures can bear more weight, whereas Tiny creatures can carry less. For each size category above Medium, double the creature's carrying capacity and the amount it can push, drag, or lift. For a Tiny creature, halve these weights.

If I am reading this correctly, the carrying capacity (mount) of a creature would be the drake's strength (16) times 15, so 240 lbs (which is already enough to carry him, but still). However, when tied to a land vehicle, the drake's weight limit would then double to 480 lbs, which would be strong enough to carry possibly 2 adventurers.

**Am I reading this right, or did I miss something?**

As an aside, if my understanding is correct, that would suggest that the 12 rhosgobel (almiraj STR 2) that pulled Radagast's sled would be able to effectively pull 720 lbs, minus the 300 lbs [sled](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/sled), so in effect still be plausible both in reality (cause those weren't CGI hares) and in D&D... that is as long as they don't need the "mount" tag...

[image: Radagast being pulled by 12 Rhosgobel]

Comment: too bad the gifs didn't work, but still hope the visuals help

Comment: They were uploaded as .png's it seems, I used a gif in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/179745/62294).

Comment: Where does the term rohsgobel for the rabbits come from? I thought it was the name of [Radagast's home](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Rhosgobel), with a Sindarin meaning of "brown dwelling", is this from the movies?

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Originally, IRL they are called Flemish Giant, but Peter Jackson added them to the movie. To answer your question, even the fandom you linked calls them Rhosgobel, and so does Radagast in this clip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3A01_ef_mtM&ab_channel=ArthasFrost

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin If that link works wierd (as it did for me), this link shows Radagast's line "These are Rhosgobel Rabbits, I'd like to see them try" at the very end.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_25-FvOPGY&ab_channel=MenoftheWest

Comment: @VictorB, I think that explains it. They are "Rhosgobel Rabbits", i.e. rabbits from Rhosgobel (fandom link [here](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Rhosgobel_Rabbits)), like you would say "Florida Alligators". Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Had to pick a link cause I dunno how to put it in a word, but you're welcome

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### This should work, and better than you originally thought.

The rules for pulling a cart state:

> An animal pulling a carriage, cart, chariot, sled, or wagon can move weight up to five times its base carrying capacity, including the weight of the vehicle. If multiple animals pull the same vehicle, they can add their carrying capacity together.
>
> -["Mounts and Vehicles"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#MountsandVehicles), *Basic Rules*

So the drake should be able to pull up to five times its base carrying capacity when hitched to a wagon, which looks to be up to 1200 pounds.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136913/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-markov-can-a-non-mount-pull-a-cart).

Comment: So, what you're saying is that my bugbear with a strength of 20 can pull a cart weighing up to 3000 pounds. My DM is gonna love this. :)

Answer (score 7):

### Creatures can pull vehicles of five times carrying capacity pounds

There is nothing in the rules that says only mounts can pull vehicles. To the contrary, the rules speak about *animals* in general, and the table  on p. 156 PHB that is listing examples is called *Mounts **and other animals***.

[Thomas' answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/198920/can-a-non-mount-pull-a-cart/198921#198921) gives you the relevant rule that

> An animal pulling a carriage, cart, chariot, sled, or wagon can move weight up to five times its base carrying capacity, including the weight of the vehicle

The carrying capacity of common animals is listed in the **Mounts and Other Animals** table. For animals which have no carrying capacity listed there, you can calculate the carrying capacity as follows (in part as per rules on p. 176 PHB that you cite):

1. Unadjusted carrying capacity = Strength score x 15 lbs
2. Apply relevant features such as **Beast of Burden** or **Powerful Build**
3. Double for each size category above Medium, half for Tiny.

This will give you the "base carrying capacity" mentioned in the rule.

For example, if you look at the [mule](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16960-mule) in the table, its carring capacity is 420 lbs, and the is a Medium size animal with Strength 14 and the **Beast of Burden** feature that says "*The mule is considered to be a Large animal for the purpose of determining its carrying capacity*". So it will be doubling its carrying capacity. This will give you 14 x 15 lbs x 2 = 420 lbs, as listed in the table. It would be able to pull a cart of  2,100 lbs. This rule works for all animals in the table.